# Connect to SQL server from PHP via odbc connection with Windows authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, odbc

I'm trying to connect to a local SQL server from a PHP srcipt using odbc_connect, but I can't log in.

This is my code so far:

```
$user= "PC_NAME\PC_USER";
$password="";
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;";
$link = odbc_connect("$dsn", $user, $password);
```

Can you see anything wrong?

Comment: No, can't see anything. Are you getting any errors? Are you checking for errors?

Comment: I just keep getting this error: Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error de inicio de sesi�n del usuario 'diegodell\Patsy'., SQL state 28000 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\proveedoresbcdtravel\config.php on line 16

Comment: And that translates to?

Comment: Something like "login error for user MyPc\MyUser"

Comment: You'll need to double-check your credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bad configuration in my SQL Server. I had to allow SQL login besides the default Windows login